# filter objects from a model if a foreign key field contains the logged in user

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from notifications.models import Notification
from django.shortcuts import render,Http404,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Q


def TrainerDashView(request):
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
     return redirect('accounts:index')
  else:
    print(request.user.username)
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver__username__in 
    = request.user.username)
    count=Notification.objects.filter(receiver__username__in = 
    request.user.username).count()
    print("NOTIFYNIUM: ",count)
    context={
       'notifications':notifications,

     }

    return render(request,'trainer_dash.html',context)
```

My Model Notification contains a field called receiver which is a foreign key to all User model.I want to select all objects in Notication if the receiver field contains current logged in user. My code is not returning any objects even aven though user activated from admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter `__in=x` compares to each of the elements in the *iterable* `x`. In your case, `x` is a string, so you are filtering for notifications whose receiver's username is excactly one of the *characters* in `request.user.username`. Just remove the `__in`:

```
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver__username=request.user.username)
```

or even better, filter on the user directly:

```
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
```

Comment: The only situation I'd filter on `username` here instead of directly on the foreign key would be if usernames were non-unique and I expected to sometimes get multiples. Sticking to the primary key (implicit in the second example) ensures it's unique, non-null, and indexed; some or all of these things might not be true in the case that you're dealing with a custom user model (or, more generally, any other relation where you'd have the option of querying the PK when you're expecting a single result).

Answer (score 1):

There's an even shorter version, which uses the related_name of the ForeignKey. Assuming you haven't changed the default:

```
notifications = request.user.notification_set.all()
```